# Android how to open fragment from listview element

Tags: android, android-fragments

In `MainActivity` is FrameLayout `MainContainer`. I load there a fragment `TrainerMyGroups`, there is a Listview where I add a few elements (each element has some strings) by use `TrainerGroupsAdapter`. Actually I want to replace fragment `TrainerMyGroups` by another (for example `TrainersInfo`) by click on list's element.

My `TrainerGroupsAdapter` is:

```
public class TrainerGroupsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public TrainerGroupsAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class Datahandler{
        TextView name;
        TextView when;
        TextView where;
        LinearLayout ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row=convertView;
        Datahandler handler;
        SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mygroups,parent,false);
            handler = new Datahandler();
            handler.name =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainermygroupslistname);
            handler.where =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainermygroupslistwhere);
            handler.when =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainermygroupslistwhen);
            handler.ll=(LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.trainermygroupslistlayout);
            row.setTag(handler);
        }
        else {
            handler = (Datahandler)row.getTag();
        }

        TrainerGroupsDataProvider dataProvider;
        dataProvider = (TrainerGroupsDataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        handler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        handler.when.setText(dataProvider.getWhen());
        handler.where.setText(dataProvider.getWhere());
        handler.ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + dataProvider.getColor()));


        handler.ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContainer, new TrainerInfo()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

}
```

It doesn't work but method OnClick is probably good because if I replace `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContainer, new TrainerInfo()).addToBackStack(null).commit();` to code for change some strings (name, when tc) it works. Problem is in `getFragmentMenager()`, Android Studio shows message that I have to create Getter and AS's suggestion is to generate in OnClick method:

```
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
      return fragmentManager;
}
```

then problem is in the second argument in `replace`, I have error that it has to be Fragment (Im sure that `TrainersInfo()` is fragment because I use it in other place and it works).
How can I solve this problem or what is the best way to open fragment by click on lise's element in another fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**#UPDATE2**

Better then replacing the Fragment inside the adapter is to say your activity that it should replace the fragment. This can be done with an interface which you implement inside your Activity:

```
public class TrainerGroupsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    // The interface which you have to implement in your activity
    public interface OnChangeFragmentListener {
        void changeFragment();
    }

    List list = new ArrayList();
    private OnChangeFragmentListener m_onChangeFragmentListener;

    public TrainerGroupsAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        m_onChangeFragmentListener = (OnChangeFragmentListener) context;
    }

    // Your other code

}
```

The OnClickListener in your getView Method:

```
handler.ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Call the method which change the fragment
        m_onChangeFragmentListener.changeFragment();
    }
});
```

The Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TrainerGroupsAdapter.OnChangeFragmentListener {

    //...
    //  Your Other code

    // Implement the method which is called in the adapter and replace the fragment here
    @Override
    public void changeFragment() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContainer, new TrainerInfo()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

**#UPDATE1**

You need an activity context for getSupportFragmentManager() and getFragmentManager().
You can change the Context parameter of the constructor to Activity and create a member variable in your class for the activity so you can use it later:

```
public class TrainerGroupsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();
    private Activity m_activity;

    public TrainerGroupsAdapter(Activity context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        m_activity = context;
    }
    // Your other code
}
```

The OnClickListener in your getView method:

```
   handler.ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m_activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContainer, new TrainerInfo()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
   });
```

Comment: I tried but there is the same problem (getSupportFragmentManager() is 'red' and AS suggest to create getters,then new Trainersinfo() is wrong argument).

Comment: Is getSupportFragmentManager() always red or only when you try to use it in the onClick method?

Comment: always in public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method

Comment: You need an activity context for getFragmentManager() and getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: what does means m_activity = m_activity?

Comment: Sry it was a mistake it should mean : `m_activity = context;` And where you create your TrainerGroupsAdapter adapter you pass the activity context to your adapters constructor. When you create your Adapter in a Activity it is ony a `this` and inside a Fragment `getActivity()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but actually problem is with arguments (error is: replace(int, android.app.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (int, com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.TrainerInfo))

Comment: Did your TrainerInfo Fragment use android.support.v4.app.Fragment or android.app.fragment? You can see it with the imports in your Fragment class.

Comment: TrainerInfo use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Then you have to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). I have add a cleaner solution to my answer but if you plan to implement the cleaner implementation, first check if it works with getSupportFragmentManager() with the old solution.

Comment: 'old solution' u mean without m_activity? there is problem with getSupportFragmentManager() (need getters again), if I use m_activity.getSupportFragmentManager()~ there is: "Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'"

Comment: If your use getSupportFragmentManager() you have to change `private Activity m_activity;` to  `private  AppCompatActivity m_activity;` and the constructor parameters from `public TrainerGroupsAdapter(Activity context, int resource)` to `public TrainerGroupsAdapter(AppCompatActivity context, int resource)`. This only works when your Activity is from type "AppCompatActivity", too. With old solution I mean the solution which we are discussing at the moment and with new the one which is under "UPDATE2" in my answer.

Comment: I tried "UPDATE2" and there is the same problem but finally it works by "old solution" (with  private AppCompatActivity m_activity; but Activity context in constructor). Thank you very much man!

Comment: Nice to hear that it works for you, can you then accept my answer please? UPDATE2 solution need getSupportFragmentManager(), too. But also only work if the Activity is from type AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Was searching for a similar answer, and got one from a good friend and android dev. I think it's the easiest one to understand and implement. SO I am usually creating a helper class in which I put my two static functions for opening fragments (as replace or dialog):

For example the replace one:

```java
public static void openFragmentReplace(Activity activity, int idOfPlacement, Fragment fragment) 
    final FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(idOfPlacement, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and the dialog one:

```java
public static void openFragmentAsDialog(Activity activity, DialogFragment fragment) {
    final FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment.show(fm, "tag");
}
```

Then I just call it from where I want like this:

```java
Helper.openFragmentReplace(getActivity(),R.id.PlaceForFragment,FragmentClass newFrag);
```

This seems like the best and easiest way to do it!

Hope it helps.